# what is plain object ?? I read this from next.js api official website

Tags: object, next.js

`Notice that to load data when the page loads, we use getInitialProps which is an async static method. It can asynchronously fetch anything that resolves to a JavaScript **plain Object**, which populates props.

Data returned from getInitialProps is serialized when server rendering, similar to a JSON.stringify. Make sure the returned object from getInitialProps is a **plain Object** and not using Date, Map or Set.

For the initial page load, getInitialProps will execute on the server only. getInitialProps will only be executed on the client when navigating to a different route via the Link component or using the routing APIs.`

this phrases are from [https://nextjs.org/docs/#fetching-data-and-component-lifecycle]

I do not understand what plain object is... can anyone please clarify that for me??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In vanilla JavaScript a POJO (Plain Old JavaScript Object) is the simplest kind of object you could possibly have: a set of key-value pairs, created by the `{}` object literal notation or constructed with `new Object()`.

Plain Old JavaScript Object:

Using the bracket's syntactic sugar also known as object literal:

```
const obj = {};
```

Using the `Object()` constructor:

```
const obj = new Object();
```